# Order of operations of escape characters

Tags: javascript, string

I was playing around with strings particularly, I had a javascript program that evaluated

```
console.log('\\'')
>> '\''
```

SO i'm trying to understand how the "escape" character order of operations worked. 
Is it the case that (here parenthesis enforce order of operations and aren't part of the string actually)

```
'\\'' = '\(\')'
```

Or is it:

```
'\\'' = '(\\)''
```

That is are the escape operator evaluating from left to right or right to left?

I realized that the code above doesn't render according to the order of operations:

### The original problem:

```
console.log("\" '\\'' \"")
>> " '\'' "
```

Comment: `console.log('\\'')` throws an error

Comment: Just curious, what JavaScript engine did you use that actually evaluated `'\\''`? It should always throw an error. Latest versions of Chrome, Firefox and Node.js definitely do.

Comment: The expression was nested in a larger string, I didn’t think it mattered but it seems to. I will edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From left to right so in `'\\''` first `\\` then `'` - and this will cause error - so `'\\''` is invalid statement

```js
'\\''
```

but this one is valid:

```js
'\''
```